# NHibernate Oracle Connection?

Tags: nhibernate

I am setting up an Oracle connection for NHibernate for the first time. I have copied the Oracle.DataAccess.dll file into my bin folder. No matter what I try, I keep getting the same error:

```
Could not load type >NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver. Possible cause: no assembly name specified.
```

I am using the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory name="DefaultSessionFactory">
        <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">>NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=DB;User ID=USERPassword=****;</property>       
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping assembly="NHibernateExample.DataAccess"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have previously only set up NHibernate for SQL Server. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you copy and paste the code? because there's an extra > in there, in the connection.driver_class line

Comment: I feel braindead. I must have been over that config file 20x. Thanks for having a sharp eye. Up and running.

Answer (score 2):

Semi colon seperator missed between user id value and password.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent step by step tutorial on connecting NHibernate to Oracle:
http://nhbwithoracle.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Once I had a similar problem, and I fixed it by adding `hibernate` to the property names, in your case:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.connection_string">Data Source=DB;User ID=USERPassword=****;</property>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: No the hibernate. was removed from the configuration some time ago. Most samples still include it so you need to delete that sometimes.