# Build NHibernate ORM from Oracle database

Tags: .net, oracle, nhibernate, orm

I'm analyzing a project in asp.net with mvc and would like to use NHibernate as ORM.
All over the net I find books, tutorials, quick start guides to work with SQL and Linq-to-Sql but allmost never for Oracle.

What is the best setup?

In my project we have a rather small database in Oracle and I prefer to have model that is created based on the database ( is that even possible? ) Or do I have to seperate the 2.

Cant this be done cause the connection string is setup in the config file if I'm correct. So we do have direct access to the structure in the Oracle db.

Just as info: As you notice, I'm a new user of these, but it's hard to make those choices on a higher level. My knowledge on this comes from PHP world where simular methods and technologies are used...

if there are good tutorials or books on that topic, let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using NHibernate with Oracle: you only need to set up the correct dialect, driver and connection string. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241086/nhibernate-oracle-connection) as an example.

Generating your model from the database: you can use [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/frameworks#nhibernate), [Visual NHibernate](http://www.slyce.com/), [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=1505), ...

Books on NHibernate: [NHibernate in Action](http://www.manning.com/kuate/), [NHibernate 3.0 Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/nhibernate-3-0-cookbook/book)

Comment: wow all answers in one post! superb! Which one do you recommend for model generation?